# How to aggregate with Python Lambda function for column A by column id?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am aggregating for many columns in my dataframe. Now, I want to create a df_8 in which I want to say that for all unique ids, just paste the value of column os. When I run the first aggregation part, I dont get an error. But, when I run the next step of merging all aggregated dataframes, it does not work. The only new change to my script is the addition of df_8 (os aggregation). 
Why?

```
AGGREGATION
    df_test=df[['id','date','purchase','days1','days2','inactivity','visitnumber','total_duration','os']].copy()

    df_1=df_test.groupby(['id'])["date"].apply(lambda z : ((z.max()-z.min()) + '1D')).astype('timedelta64[D]').reset_index()
    df_2=df_test.groupby(['id'])["purchase"].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
    df_3=df_test[df_test['days1'].gt(0)].groupby('id')['date'].count().astype(int)
    df_4=df_test.groupby(['id'])["days2"].apply(lambda t : t.astype(int).count()).reset_index()
    df_5=df_test.groupby(['id'])["total_duration"].apply(lambda f : (today-f.min())+'1D').astype('timedelta64[D]').reset_index()
    df_6=df_test[df_test['days1'].gt(0)].groupby(['id'])['inactivity'].apply(lambda j: (today - j.max())).astype('timedelta64[D]')
    df_7=df_test[df_test['purchase'].gt(0)].groupby(['id'])['visitnumber'].apply(lambda i : i.astype(int).count()).reset_index()
    **df_8=df_test.groupby(['id'])['os'].apply(lambda h: h).reset_index()**

MERGING OF ALL DFs
df_a=pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df_b=pd.merge(df_a, df_3, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df_c=pd.merge(df_b, df_4, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df_d=pd.merge(df_c, df_5, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df_e=pd.merge(df_d, df_6, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df_f=pd.merge(df_e, df_7, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)
df  =pd.merge(df_f, df_8, on='id', how='left').fillna(0)

df.head()

Error: KeyError: 'id'
```

Comment: @ALollz sorry, I mistyped the id in with merge statement. just corrected it but the line that throws an error in the merge part is: df  =pd.merge(df_f, df_8, on='userid', how='left').fillna(0) this one

Comment: `df_8` really doesn't make any sense. The problem is that your `groupby` gets rid of the `'id'` column and you're probably left with a DataFrame that has 2 columns `['index', 'os']`. But again, that `groupby` isn't really doing anything, perhaps you mean `df_8 = df_test[['id', 'os']]`? Or how do you want to aggregate `'os'`?

Comment: @ALollz it worked!!!! Thanks so much.